# c# autocomplete text box using only part of inputted text

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I want to implement the autocomplete feature in a textbox using only part of the text the user inputs. For example, if the user inputs "123 abc", i want autocomplete to work with just the "abc" part.

I have tried filling a hashset with the data (over 500,000 items). Then using the regex `@"^[\d]*\s*"` to successfully remove the numbers and space from the start of the string so I am left only with "abc" (but **i want to leave the numbers in the textbox**) and then populating a list using `value.StartsWith("abc")` by iterating through each value in the hashset. Finally I add all the filtered items to a combo boxes items.

This method is very slow and gives me pauses of upto 5 seconds or longer, the text box autocomplete method is much quicker and better implemented. Can I use the textbox autocomplete with only part of the string or is there some other implementation you can suggest that is equally fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried / considered a binary search method? It could be considerably faster...

You would just need to add them all to a list, sort it then use it in the search as code below shows...

The alternative would be to store it in an indexed database which would be quite fast using text indexing.

For example...

List.BinarySearch will return the ones complement of the index of the next item larger than the request if an exact match is not found.

```
//So, you can do it like this (assuming you'll never get an exact match):

var key = (cardName + Config.EditionShortToLong(edition)).ToLower();
var list = CardBase.cardList;

var index = ~list.BinarySearch(key);
return index != list.Count && list[index].StartsWith(key);
```

Good luck...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

        dinosaurs.Add("Pachycephalosaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSort");
        dinosaurs.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nBinarySearch and Insert \"Coelophysis\":");
        int index = dinosaurs.BinarySearch("Coelophysis");
        if (index < 0)
        {
            dinosaurs.Insert(~index, "Coelophysis");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nBinarySearch and Insert \"Tyrannosaurus\":");
        index = dinosaurs.BinarySearch("Tyrannosaurus");
        if (index < 0)
        {
            dinosaurs.Insert(~index, "Tyrannosaurus");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }
    }
}
```